# Installing glibtop on ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, glib

I'm new to ubuntu and i'm currently using it on windows 7 with vmware workstation.
I need to access the CPU usage with a C program on terminal, so i thought of using `glibtop_get_cpu()` function on glibtop library. I just wrote `#include <glibtop.h>` in my code and compiled it with "gcc" on terminal, and it said

```
fatal error: glibtop.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I tried to install the library using this:

```
sudo apt-get install liblib2.0-dev
```

but the terminal said:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libglib2.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin
E: Package 'libglib2.0-dev' has no installation candidate
```

any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2):

You should install libgtop2-dev (`sudo apt-get install libgtop2-dev`).